# java-With multicastSocket, recipients can not receive broadcasts

Tags: java

Learning java MulticastSocket, the same LAN only the machine can receive the broadcast, the other equipment can not. why? Is the router setting problem or the broadcast address setting problem?
send.java

```
public class sentServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "224.0.0.1";
        int port = 9998;String message = "test-multicastSocket";
        try {
            InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            MulticastSocket s = new MulticastSocket();
            s.joinGroup(group);
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(),message.length(),group,port);
            s.send(dp);
            s.close();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The listening address set here is 224.0.0.1

recevier.java

```
public class reClinet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host="224.0.0.1";
        int port=9998;
        int length=1024;
        byte[] buf=new byte[length];
        MulticastSocket ms=null;
        DatagramPacket dp=null;
        StringBuffer sbuf=new StringBuffer();
        try {
            ms=new MulticastSocket(port);
            dp=new DatagramPacket(buf,length);
            InetAddress group=InetAddress.getByName(host);
            ms.joinGroup(group);
            System.out.println("port is open");
            ms.receive(dp);
            ms.close();
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<1024;i++){
                if(buf[i]==0){
                    break;
                }
                sbuf.append((char)buf[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("message"+sbuf.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are asking: why can only systems attached to the same network segment see broadcasts?

That is the **nature** of [broadcasts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html) in Java: a client connects to a specific server; and joins the broadcast group; then that client will be notified.

If a client doesn't get those notifications; you have to look into your network settings, firewalls, ...